# How to specify entity to authenticate against

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony with FOSUserBundle for authentication. I think that by default it authenticates against an entity called User. I can't use that as it's already used for something else. What is the easiest way of authenticating against a different entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by defining your user class with the name of your choice and putting its name in the configuration.

Let's call this class `JamesUser`.

Define your entity:

```
<?php
// src/James/UserBundle/Entity/JamesUser.php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class JamesUser extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

And in your config file, make sure you are using the right class:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: James\UserBundle\Entity\JamesUser
```

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle